# Pandas dataframe merging with some constraints

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes that I want to merge in a specific way which is described below.

Example dataframes:

```
   key  prob  map
0  ABC   NaN  AAA
1  PQR  0.64  PPP
2  SUV  0.80  SSS

   key  prob  txt
0  ABC  0.75  CCC
1  SUV  0.89  VVV
2  XYZ  0.68  ZZZ
3  PQR  1.00  RRR
```

To generate the example dataframes, use:

```
t_dict = {'key':['ABC', 'PQR', 'SUV'], 'prob':[np.nan, 0.64, 0.80], 'map':['AAA', 'PPP', 'SSS']}
t_df = pd.DataFrame(t_dict)

main_dict = {'key':['ABC', 'SUV', 'XYZ', 'PQR'], 'prob':[0.75, 0.89, 0.68, 1.00], 'txt':['CCC', 'VVV', 'ZZZ', 'RRR']}
main_df = pd.DataFrame(main_dict)
```

The logic of the merging is something like the following:

> If `prob` is not NA, then in the first step I want to put the corresponding value from the `map` column to the `main_df`, where `key` value matches and `prob` value is greater than or equals to one present in `t_df`, but less than or equals to `1.00`. For cases where `prob` value is NA in `t_df`, I'll just merge based on `key` column.

The final dataframe I want to return is something like this:

```
    key  prob  txt  map
0  SUV  0.89  VVV  SSS
1  PQR     1  RRR  PPP
2  ABC  0.75  CCC  AAA
```

Now, the code I'm currently using for merging:

```
t_df['UniqueKey'] = ''
t_df.loc[:, 'UniqueKey'] = t_df['UniqueKey'].transform(lambda g:uuid4().hex)
t_df['prob'] = t_df['prob'].dropna().apply(lambda x: [i/100 for i in range(int(100*x), 101) if i/100 in main_df['prob'].unique().tolist()])
t_df = t_df.explode('prob', ignore_index=True)
all_keys_list = ['key', 'prob']
merge_key_list = [['key', 'prob'], ['key']]
temp_df = op_df[op_df['map'].notna()]
uuid_list = temp_df['UniqueKey'].unique().tolist()
t_df = t_df.loc[~t_df['UniqueKey'].isin(uuid_list)]

output_list = list()
for elem in merge_key_list:
    op_df = pd.merge(main_df, t_df.drop(columns=list(set(all_keys_list) ^ set(elem))), how='left', on=elem)
    temp_df = op_df[op_df['map'].notna()]
    uuid_list = temp_df['UniqueKey'].unique().tolist()
    t_df = t_df.loc[~t_df['UniqueKey'].isin(uuid_list)]
    output_list.append(temp_df)
    main_df = op_df[op_df['map'].isna()].drop(columns=['UniqueKey', 'map'])
merged_df = pd.concat(output_list)
final_df = merged_df.reset_index().drop(columns=['index', 'UniqueKey'])
```

Because of the `explode` method, the `t_df` becomes pretty large for large `main_df`. And in my case, both the dataframes can be pretty large (`t_df` of scale 200 rows, `main_df` of scale 500k rows). So this process becomes a lot more computationally expensive.

So, is there any better, more elegant way to do it?